# Pronunciation of "especially"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

In some podcasts (it seems the speaker was from California) I heard that the word "especially" was pronounced with "ks" sound like "ikspeshally".

What was it likely to be, personal way of pronouncing this word or a local dialect?

Comment: It's a common mispronunciation. Which is why it's commonly misspelled ["expecially"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=expecially&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cexpecially%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I live in Idaho and I hear people pronounce *especially* this way all of the time.

More often than not (at least around here) it gets pronounced either "ex-specially" or "eck-specially" or "eg-specially". There are many people here who have their own dialect.

Don't even ask me about "creek" and "crick"...

Comment: O.o, I'm so sorry...Seriously, I'm pretty liberal when it comes to pronunciation, but why would people pronounce letters that aren't there??

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think that the speaker was maybe raised in Idaho and only later moved to California

Comment: @kitukwfyer - Actually, I suspect that ignorance is partly to blame (ie - mispronounce it because they actually think its spelled that way)... who knows though.

Comment: @kitukwfyer: remember that it's *spoken* language that is primary, at least in native speakers. So it's not "people pronounce letters that aren't there", but the other way round: the spelling does not reflect the actual pronunciation (in that dialect). As soon as you put it that way, it's obvious that this is nothing special (and not just in English, I might add). And no matter how much time you give it, spelling might or might not adapt to the pronunciation. (On the one hand, we no longer write *thrid*, we actually write *third*; on the other hand, we still write *women* rather than *wimin*.)

Comment: @Regdwight Haha, yeah. This one just caught me off guard because I'd never seen/heard it before and because I've been learning words from books years before I heard them for quite some time. Still, that comment is pretty empty-headed in retrospect. I should probably get out more. X)

Comment: @kitukwfyer: *"why would people pronounce letters that aren't there?"* How do you pronounce *colonel*? *Edinburgh*?

Answer (score 7):

I checked more than 10 dictionaries and the pronunciation of "especially" is given as:

> **/ɪˈspɛʃ(ə)li, ɛ-/**

It's probably the personal way of pronouncing that word for the relevant person, which seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 4):

I was born and raised in California. I've spent time in many different Californian locales, and I have never heard that pronunciation.

I think the speaker misspoke or was trying to be cute.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard that pronunciation from people with Appalachian roots, but I think it is rare there. The same people tend to pronounce "nuclear" as "nucular", so the pattern seems to be to convert unusual (for the dialect) diphthongs to something more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I was raised in California and have heard that occasionally. I do not think it is a regional dialect in the sense that there is some part of California in which everyone speaks that way. It's more likely to be a social dialect of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I am a native Southeast Texan, and most people pronounce especially with the "k" sound where I live. This has been a lifelong peeve to me, as I do not pronounce it that way myself. I pronounce it as it is spelled. I was an avid reader as a child, and saw it written before I ever heard it spoken.

Answer (score 0):

Pronunciation of "especially" is: [*`/ə ˈspɛʃ li/`*](http://www.beedictionary.com/definition/especially) or [*`/iˈspeSHəlē/`*](http://www.google.com/dictionary?langpair=en|en&q=especially&hl=en&aq=f).

Listen pronunciation from [BeeDictionary](http://www.beedictionary.com/definition/especially) or [Google Dictionary](http://www.google.com/dictionary?langpair=en|en&q=especially&hl=en&aq=f)

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a mash-up with words like "exclusively", "exceptionally", etc.

That kind of thing happens a lot.

Answer (score -2):

I heard a professor just today pronounce ["especially"](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/especially) as *expeshulee*.

Answer (score -2):

> I heard that the word "especially" was pronounced with "ks" sound like
>   "ikspeshally".

That pronunciation is really weird. The word *especially* (at least in England and the rest of the UK) is normally pronounced with a certain "*e*" sound at the beginning, like the pronunciation of the letter *e* in the words *bed*, *debt* and *get*. In addition to that, it does not normally and is not supposed to have, a "*ks*" sound. It normally has an "*s*" sound there.

> What was it likely to be, personal way of pronouncing this word or a
>   local dialect?

It was probably just a personal way of mispronouncing, mangling the word.